# ubuntu 16.04 snappy core and opening pdf files

Tags: 16.04, pdf, evince, ubuntu-core, snap

Is it possible to have all pdf files open in a snappy core project / application to prevent infection of the main machine OS? If so how?   PDf files are increasingly being infected with some type of malware and I'm hoping that snap apps will help prevent this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question. The short answer to your question is yes, you could snap up evince (or similar). The longer answer is: as long as there's an insecure protocol involved, you will be at risk. Remember that on the current desktop, even if using a Snap package, if it has a GUI it has to be using X11, which is an inherently insecure protocol. So while packaging the PDF viewer as a snap would likely be helpful in defeating some attacks, it won't be a perfect solution until Ubuntu moves away from X (to Mir, presumably).